# 100% Width and Height of Sizable Parent Div - CSS

Tags: css

Lets say I have two divs....

```
<div class="Window">
    <div class='Title'></div>
    <div class="Viewer"></div>
</div>
```

First is the window that opens up which is .Window

```
.Window {
    width:80%;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:10%;
    left:10%;
    margin-left: 0%;
    bottom:10%;
}
```

The second div is .Viewer

```
.Viewer {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:green;
}
```

How do I get the .Viewer div to go 100% height and width of the parent div. Keep in mind .Title takes up space as it is the title of the .Window. Therefore .Viewer has to start below .Title

Comment: I'm confused... you say "the .Viewer div to go 100% height and width of the parent div" but then say ".Viewer has to start below .Title" ... so which is it? Your code seems fine to me.

Comment: I think he wants the `.Viewer` div to take up the rest of the space if there is content in the `.Title`. The way it currently is it will overflow out of the `.Window`, atleast on Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/qHe29/

Comment: This is true @Danny. It overflows the .Window if I have content in the title. Right now I have line-height:50px; for .Title

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible without JS if your *.Title* has a fixed height (*.Title* and *.Viewer* could have 10% and 90% heights, for example, which should work without JS).

-- edited (didn't see the other parameters. this part is **invalid**) --

But I have also noticed that your *.Windows* has not *height* parameter. What is the *.Viewer* supposed to fill by having a 100% height? By default divs expand as much, as they need, so in your (current) case *.Window* would have a height of *.Title* height plus *.Viewer* height, which, as I understand, is pretty much what you are asking for.

Comment: There is a top and bottom value, so that will set the height of the div relative to the size of the browser.

Comment: The `height` of an absolute positioned element with `top` and `bottom` gets calculated automatically.

Comment: Ahh, missed that out. Didn't notice these parameters. My bad.